# ORA-44002 Invalid object name on a function body

Tags: sql, oracle

```
DECLARE 
      X VARCHAR2(32767);
    BEGIN
      X := '
      SELECT to_char(days.n, ''DD/MM/YYYY HH24'') as name,
             NVL(ROUND(AVG(s1.HIGH),2),-1) HIGH
      FROM  (SELECT TO_DATE('''||:P8_DATE_DEBUT||''', ''DD/MM/YYYYHH24'')+(level-1)/TO_NUMBER('''||:P8_ECHELLE||''') as n
             FROM   dual
             CONNECT BY level <= TO_DATE('''||:P8_DATE_FIN||''', ''DD/MM/YYYYHH24'')+1-TO_DATE('''||:P8_DATE_DEBUT||''', ''DD/MM/YYYYHH24''))*TO_NUMBER('''||:P8_ECHELLE||''')      
            ) days
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (SELECT trunc(RAW_DATE, '''||:P8_TRUNC||''') as HO,
                    NVL(ROUND(AVG(VALID_VALUE),2), 0) as HIGH
             FROM  '||
                   dbms_assert.sql_object_name('SAFEGE.MSR_'||NVL(:P8_ECHELLE_EMMA,'4245')) -- NVL better than COALESCE for a simple Null check
                   ||'@EMMASAFE.NTSIVOA'
                   ||'
             WHERE RAW_DATE >= TO_DATE('''||:P8_DATE_DEBUT||''', ''DD/MM/YYYY'')  -- avoiding BETWEEN means less messing about with time components
             AND   RAW_DATE <  TO_DATE('''||:P8_DATE_FIN||''', ''DD/MM/YYYY'')+1  -- just need to use less than target date+1 instead
             AND   VALIDITY = 1
             GROUP BY trunc(RAW_DATE, '''||:P8_TRUNC||''') 
            ) s1
            ON days.n = S1.HO
      GROUP BY days.n
      ORDER BY days.n';
      RETURN X;
    END;
```

I get an invalid object name error on this function body. I cannot locate the line where this error appears. Any idea on how to solve this syntax error ?

Regards,
Christian

Answer (score 1):

It is this line:

```sql
dbms_assert.sql_object_name('SAFEGE.MSR_'||NVL(:P8_ECHELLE_EMMA,'4245'))
```

The [`DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME` function documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_assert.htm#ARPLS65391) states that:

> This function verifies that the input parameter string is a qualified SQL identifier of an existing SQL object.

You are asserting that the object exists but you are concatenating it, outside the assertion, with `@EMMASAFE.NTSIVOA` which would be across a database link. The server you are running the query on cannot assert that the object name is valid because it may not exist on that server (and instead exists on the remote server).

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b3ff5e14ac0f355f6cf46561e8d2b332)

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the function. But now I get ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis on line 8 :

FROM  (SELECT TO_DATE('''||:P8_DATE_DEBUT||''', ''DD/MM/YYYYHH24'')+(level-1)/TO_NUMBER('''||:P8_ECHELLE||''') as n
FROM   dual